# Show price in prestashop

Tags: php, content-management-system, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I am using prestashop 1.6 and in my front-office the product price is not showing when the user is not logged , I've searching all around google and try different solution inside the back-office but nothing work,

here is the code inside my template

```
      {if !$priceDisplay}
      {convertPrice price=$product.price}
      {else}
      {convertPrice price=$product.price_tax_exc}
      {/if}
```

I try to dump the price content but there is nothing inside it when the user is not logged

my goal is to show price even for user who is not logged

Comment: what do you mean (what variable) by "price content"? Where you dumb it? In template or in `convertPrice` plugin?

Comment: I am talking about 'price=$product.price' and i dump it inside template directly after product image , i mean outside of all condition

Comment: ps i've dumped '$product' too and it show me all info about the product except the price

Comment: `price=$product.price` will be empty after `convertPrice`. So you need make sure you have `$product.PRICEXXX` value, than you can pass it to `convertPrice` function. If you don't have it you need to search them in place when you assign `$product` to view

Comment: @r_a_f can you please tell me where to search , i've read /class/Product.php and make some modification inside it , to search for price but nothing happen ,  when i dump product {$product|@var_dump} it show  me an array(size=64) and in price item i have  "'price' => boolean false" when the user is not logged , but if user is logged i got "'price' => float 48384"

Comment: ok so `$product.price` is good name. So now you need to search where $product is generated, somewhere in upper layer of your app. And modify/extend this class and delete conditional (loggedin/not) price key/property value.

Comment: you mean inside /controller/front/productController.php file

Answer (score 0):

In your admin panel go to **Customers/Groups** and enable **Show prices** for all groups. It seems that the problem is there

Comment: I already do that and try all admin panel trick ,but none of them work that's why i try to edit php code directly, so could you tell me where to start please

Comment: Ok, then can you explain on what page are you trying to get prices? Is it product page or product listing page?

Comment: The user get the product listing page before and when he click on a product he got product page
So I want to show price inside product listing: product-list-item.tpl   
Inside the product-list.tpl i have '{include file='./product-list-item.tpl' product=$product}'
I have dump $product and i get : C:\wamp64\www\local.test\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code:55:boolean false when the user is note logged
And C:\wamp64\www\local.test\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code:55:float 1200 when the user is connected

Comment: Basically speaking, I think that you need to dig in the class Product.php method priceCalculation() and it may lead you to SpecificPrice class getSpecificPrice method. But frankly speaking, it is a weird behavior so the problem can appear in Croup class as well

Comment: my goal is to show price so you know ... ;)
should i edit product class or inherit it

Comment: It doesn't seem that the problem is there. But it's difficult to guess because everything I tried to change in my instance of Prestashop doesn't give your result, in my case everything works as predicted.

Comment: may be you can check here https://mble.mg if you can , all product doesn't have a price but when you log in , all price appear